# Entity Framework 6.1 won't create junction table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

As a learning exercise I am trying to create a Chess website.  I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 to store the records, and am having trouble getting it to create the migration quite how I'd have thought it should.

I want to be able to retrieve a Player and a list of all the games that player has played in.

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other Properties
    public virtual Player White { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Player Black { get; protected set; }

    public Game(Player white, Player black) : this()
    {
        // Null checks

        White = white;
        Black = black;

        White.Games.Add(this);
        Black.Games.Add(this);
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other Properties
    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; protected set; }

    protected Player()
    {
        Games = new Collection<Game>();
    }
}
```

I then setup a Configuration for each:

```
public class GameConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Game>
{
    ToTable("Games");

    HasRequired(x => x.White);
    HasRequired(x => x.Black);

    // Config for other Properties
}

public PlayerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Player>
{
    ToTable("Players");

    HasMany(x => x.Games);

    // Config for other Properties
}
```

I expected the migration to create 3 tables:

- Games:  Id, White_Id, Black_Id, OtherProperties
- Players:  Id, OtherProperties
- GamePlayer:  Game_Id, Player_Id

But instead it created 2 tables:

- Games:  Id, White_Id, Black_Id, OtherProperties, ***Player_Id***
- Players: Id, OtherProperties

I could understand it adding the Player_Id column to Games if a game could only have one Player, but a Game will alway have 2 players.

In the GameConfiguration I have tried using:

```
HasRequired(x => x.White).HasMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
HasRequired(x => x.Black).HasMany().WillCascaseOnDelete(false);
```

which generated the same migration, and I have tried several variations of:

```
HasRequired(x => x.White)
    .HasMany(x => x.Games)
    .Map(t => t.ToTable("GamePlayer").MapKey("Game_Id", "Player_Id"));
HasRequired(x => x.Black)
    .HasMany(x => x.Games)
    .Map(t => t.ToTable("GamePlayer").MapKey("Game_Id", "Player_Id"));
```

which threw errors when trying to generate the migration complaining about GamePlayer not being in the model.

I'd appreciate any suggestions about what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to configure EF to populate the `Player.Games` collection correctly with your model. That is why, the migration looks different then you expect. There isn't any way to tell EF "this collection contains the games played as white or black"

You need to change your model and you have several options:

1. Instead of the single `Player.Games` collection add two collections `Player.GamesPlayedAsBlack`, `Player.GamesPlayedAsWhite` and configure two one-to-many relations ships between `Player` and `Game` entities
2. Create `GamePlayer` entity manually

   ```
   public class Game {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<GamePlayer> Players { get; set; }
   }

   public enum Color { White = 1, Black = 2}

   public class GamePlayer {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public virtual Game GamePlayed { get; set; }
       public Color PlayedAs { get; set; }
       public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
   }

   public class Player {
       public virtual ICollection<GamePlayer> Games { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, I went with option 2 in the end.